# OnBackPressed multiple instances of same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having an activity with custom list view. In my list view there are two types of items, with different layout. On items there is a switch and when I turn off the switch I go to Activity A, and when I turn on the switch I go to Activity B.

Here is my code:

```
 Switch enable = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.enable);
 enable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
              Intent intentChange = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityA.class);
                        intentChange.putExtra(PROPERTY, "test1");
              ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intentChange, 100);

                    } else {
                      Intent newIntent=newIntent(getContext(),ActivityB.class);
              ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(newIntent, 200);

                    }
                }
            });
```

In each of these activities I call this:

```
Intent changedIntent=new Intent();
    changedLimitIntent.putExtra("changed",changed);
    changedLimitIntent.putExtra("changedDesc","desc);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,changedIntent);
    finish();
```

In my activity with custom adapter I have this code:

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == ActivityA.REQUEST_CODE) {
            ....
        } else if (requestCode == ActivityB.REQUEST_CODE) {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

This work OK for me, however, when I receive the result from Activity A or Activity B on the activity with custom list view, and when I click back button is how I have this activity as many times I wait for result from other activities on back stack. I don't know what the problem is. I don't like to have my activity as many times I wait for result from other activities.

I hope I was clear with my question.

Comment: Set flag for intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` while calling your `Activity`.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP helped me.

Comment: Its cool !! Are you in android from start of your development ?

Comment: No, I am new to Android development, I started with web development (if this was your question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to launch new activity. Hope it will help you.

```
Activity_A.this.finish();
Intent intentSettings = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
intentSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
startActivity(intentSettings);
```